# logger.log returning undefined when basic calling API

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to fetch some API data to integrate into a google sheet. I'm fetching from this URL https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list. However, when I run the function, the logger returns undefined. What am I missing? This is day 2 learning how to code.

```
function myFunction() {

    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list");
    var content = res.getContentText();

    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    var list = json["id"]["symbol"];

    Logger.log(list);
}
```

Comment: because for fields _"id"_, _"symbol"_ you need to go down 1 level into JSON: `for (const el of json) {console.log(el.id, el.symbol, el.name);}`

Comment: Because the content variable will give you [{"id":"01coin","symbol":"zoc","name":"01coin"},....], so try to use var list = json[0]["symbol"] or var list = json[0].symbol, and you can't use json["id"]["symbol"] because id and symbol are the same member of array

Answer (score 0):

I think it's undefined because you're not `WAITING` for the response (which is an `ASYNC` ajax request) .. so you have to wait for it with a `PROMISE` / or / `AWAIT ASYNC` and so on ..

Try something like this:

```
async function myFunction() { //mark the func as async

    var res = await UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list"); // await the response FROM the server
    var content = res.getContentText();

    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    var list = json["id"]["symbol"];

    Logger.log(list);
}
```

OR with PROMISE:

```
function myFunction() { //mark the func as async

    UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list").then((resp) => { //await for the response FROM the server
        var res = resp;
        var content = res.getContentText();

        var json = JSON.parse(content);
        var list = json["id"]["symbol"];

        Logger.log(list);

    }).catch()

}
```

I hope it can help you!!

Comment: thanks federico, when i apply either of the code it returns "Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")"